# Coldfusion 9 DSN less Connection MSSQL 2008 Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, connection, windows-authentication

**Update:**

Though the original question asked about windows authentication, any connection method would be fine. As long as it does not require creating a DSN.

---

I'm trying to connect my database with Windows Authentication. Here is the code. 
Please advise. Thanks.

```
<cfscript>
  classLoader = createObject("java", "java.lang.Class");
  classLoader.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
  dm = createObject("java","java.sql.DriverManager");
  dburl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.3.150:1433;databasename=RsDB;integratedSecurity=true";
  con = dm.getConnection(dburl,"", "");
  st = con.createStatement();
  rs = st.ExecuteQuery("SELECT top 10 * FROM pa (nolock)");
  q = createObject("java", "coldfusion.sql.QueryTable").init(rs);   
</cfscript>

<cfoutput query="q">
  email = #email#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

ERROR :

Error Occurred While Processing Request
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

Comment: Given how easy it is to set up a ColdFusion datasource using windows authentication, why are you even attempting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an example [here](http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-database-connection-in-coldfusion/page/3/) that shows the username and password in the URL.

```
<cfset connection = driverManager
.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb?user=demouser&password=demopass")>
```

Your URL for SQL Server doesn't pass in any credentials, give that a try.

Comment: But that defeats the purpose of integrated authentication ;-)

Comment: why im using DSNless because i don't CFadmin access

Comment: Why not ask the administrator to create a DSN for you? While you can do it manually, it will be far less efficient.

Comment: i have only read production rights.. for development i have development db now i have to do some debugging on data then data i can't refresh  on development ... what im doing trying to connection with production to get records and do some debugging ... thats it

Comment: This is not a programming problem that can be solved with clever code.  You are simply being denied the tools to do your job.  Talk to your boss.

Comment: @knowledgeSeeker - While the above is perfectly valid, it is not windows authentication. Sounds like your real question was different than what you asked.  FYI: Question updated so as not to mislead the next guy searching the archives.

Answer (score 3):

(Ignoring your question for a moment, ... )

While it is possible to do it with a manual connection, is there a specific reason you cannot just use a standard DSN? That would be far more efficient and require a lot less code/cleanup. Not to mention that it avoids some of the [common pitfalls of manual connections](http://web.archive.org/web/20110317084032/http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:51085).

AFAIK, you can set the DSN to use [windows authentication](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/updated-datadirect-jdbc-drivers-version-1.html), by entering `AuthenticationMethod=Type2` under "Show Advanced Settings > Connection String". Leave the "username" and "password" fields blank.

```
<cfquery name="qTest" datasource="YourDSN">
   SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS LoginName, DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#qTest#" label="Show Connection Settings">
```

***NB:** The DSN will use the CF Service user account, so adjust as needed

**Update:**

If you absolutely must use a manual connection, try using the built in driver instead of the JDBCODBC bridge. However, be sure to *always* close the database objects. Otherwise, open connections will start to pile up and bad things will happen.

Keep in mind, opening database connections is expensive. By not using a DSN, you lose out on the benefits of connection pooling. So overall this method will be less efficient than simply using a DSN.

```
<cfscript>
   classLoader = createObject("java", "java.lang.Class");
   classLoader.forName("macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver"); 
   dm = createObject("java","java.sql.DriverManager");
   dburl = "jdbc:macromedia:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databasename=RsDB;AuthenticationMethod=Type2";
   con = dm.getConnection(dburl);
   st = con.createStatement();
   rs = st.ExecuteQuery("SELECT getDate() AS TestValue");
   q = createObject("java", "coldfusion.sql.QueryTable").init(rs); 
   // ALWAYS close all objects!
   rs.close();
   st.close();
   con.close();
   writeDump(q);
</cfscript>
```

You could also use the [SQL Server JDBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) instead. See also [Connecting with Integrated Authentication On Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Connecting). However, that requires adding the driver jars and a DLL (sqljdbc_auth.dll) to the server, which it sounds like you cannot do.

- Driver Class: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`
- URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;`